# C++ how to accept server-push data?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp

My situation: I would like to create a hobby project for improving my C++ involving real-time/latency programming.

I have decided I will write a small Java program which will send lots of random stock prices to a client, where the client will be written in C++ and accept all the prices.

I do not want the C++ client to have to poll/have a while loop which continuously checks for data even if there is none.

What options do I have for this? If it's easier to accomplish having a C++ server then that is not a problem.

I presume for starters I will have to use the boost ASIO package for networking?

I will be doing this on windows 7.

Comment: I assumed you would want to use HTTP because it's easy to use, can go across networks, through firewalls, proxies, etc.  Is that what you want?  If you are assuming a simple, directly connected network, other solutions are possible.

Comment: To be honest, the point of this project is to get my C++ back up to scratch, practice some boost and then thirdly, possibly make my code fast to accept connections. Do you know how real high frequency platforms would transmit, would it be HTTP? If not, then definitely no point in HTTP.

Comment: If you are talking about machine to machine stock stuff, I expect they'd use a binary protocol over a TCP socket.  e.g. sending a formatted, possibly fixed size message, which could be a struct.  The client would open the connection to the server, maybe send an initial message describing data of interest then have a thread or polling IO reading the responses.

Comment: HFT may very well avoid TCP in favor of UDP. Trading on old data is worse than not trading at all, so resending is not the best recovery strategy for lost packets. And that definitely excludes HTTP.

Comment: @MSalters Sure, for absolute speed UDP would be better if you don't care about potentially losing data.  Even then you could bake in your own sequence numbers to the packets and have a separate, slower but reliable connection to fill in missing data, if you need it.

Comment: @andrewmu: You're missing the point. In HFT, if you miss data, you don't resend it. Instead, you skip a trade.

Comment: Ok.  I thought some strategies involved identifying rapid changes, which would require a small window of historical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have the Java server accept connections and then wait for some duration of time. e.g. 10 seconds.  Within that time if data becomes available, send it and close the connection.

Then the C++ client can have a thread which opens a connection whenever the previous one has completed.

That should give quite low latency without creating connections very often when there is no new data.

This is basically the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)  web programming model, which is used for many applications.

Comment: I'm a little unsure why the server would accept connections, when I thought the server would dictate when connections were required?

Comment: Fundamentally, HTTP is client driven, so this is one way to allow the server to respond at a particular time, by pretty much always having an open but waiting connection.

Comment: What would be the better boost example to follow: the chat or the HTTP Server/Client?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Think about how a web server receives data.  When a URL is accessed the data is pushed to the server.  The server need not poll the client (or indeed know anything about the client other than its a service pushing bytes towards it).

You could use a Java servlet to accept the data over HTTP and write the code in this fashion.  Similarly, boost::asio has a [server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) that should get you started.  Under the hood, you could enable persistent HTTP so that the connections aren't opened /  closed frequently.  This'll make the coding model much simpler.

Comment: Hi there, I should clarify I wanted to accept the data on the C++ client. I was simply going to write a Java Server to send test data. Does this alter your suggestion? Or did you just mean use a Java servlet to send the data to the C++ client?

Comment: I presume the boost examples you were pointing me towards were "HTTP Client" and "HTTP Server"?

Comment: The same applies for client and server.  A local web server would allow you to connect in the same way.  HTTP protocol probably isn't great for real-time feedback, but it's easy to use and doesn't have firewall problems :)  The boost examples that you mention are what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want the C++ client to have to poll/have a while loop which
>   continuously checks for data

Someone HAS to.

Need not be you. I've never used boost ASIO, but it might provide a callback registration. If yes, then just register a callback function of yours with boost, boost would do the waiting and give you a call back when it gets some data.

Other option is of course that you use some functions which are synchronous. Like (not a real function) `Socket.read()` which blocks the thread until there is data in the socket or it's closed. But in this case you're dedicating a thread of your own.

--edit--

Abt the communication itself. Just pick any IPC mechanism (sockets/pipes/files/...), someone already described one I think. Once you send the data, the data itself is "encoded" and "decoded" by you, so you can create your own protocol. E.g. `"%%<STOCK_NAME>=<STOCK_PRICE>##"` where "%%", `=` and `##` (markers to mark start, mid and end) that you add on sender side and remove on receiver side to get stock name and price.

You can develop the protocol further based on your needs. Like you can also send buy/sell recommendation or, text alert msgs with major stock exchange news. As long as your client and server understand how the data is "encoded" you're good.

Finally, if you want to secure teh communication (and say you're not using some secure layer (SSL)) then you can encrypt the data. But that's a different chapter. :)

HTH

Comment: Would you be able to detail what I would be best searching for if I were to google for a boost example, consisting of what you described in your first paragraph?